# Send a QDataStream in UTF-8 from Python

Tags: python, utf-8, tcp

I am trying to use a Python3 program to send data to a C++ program using a TCP socket connection.  The receiving program will only accept a QByteArray, which can be sent from Python3.  I use a QDataStream created with the QByteArray and write my int and char data into the stream.  The problem is that I am only able to get the Python program to send my char strings as 16-bit chars, and the receiving program insists on 8-bit.

Is there some way I can get the QDataStream to contain 8-bit chars instead?

If so, an example would be much appreciated.  I have scoured the online docs, tried writeRawData, etc., and cannot get anything I have found to work.

Comment: Does your Python program also have a GUI? Or why are you using a data type from the Qt library? Sockets and binary streams can be very well handled through the standard library, where it might be easier to get the low-level specs (like word size) right.

Comment: No GUI. I have to conform to the existing C++ program with which I am trying to communicate, which insists on receiving a QByteArray with 8-bit chars.

Comment: I managed to get the data to send and be received by adding each char to the QDataStream individually, in a loop, with the WriteInt8 method of QByteArray.  I still had to pad the beginning of the text with 20 chars off junk, for some reason not known to me.